# Rspec & Rails: undefined method `to' for true:TrueClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to test one of my boolean string methods but I am getting the bellow error:

> ```
> undefined method `to' for true:TrueClass
> ```

```
describe 'is_tall?' do

  it "should return true for a tall user" do
    expect(tall_user_string.is_tall?.to be_truthy)
  end

  it "should return false for a short user" do
    expect(user_string.is_tall?.to be_falsey)
  end

end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `to` call should follow the `expect()`, not the real method. Change

```
describe 'is_tall?' do

  it "should return true for a tall user" do
    expect(tall_user_string.is_tall?.to be_truthy)
  end

  it "should return false for a short user" do
    expect(user_string.is_tall?.to be_falsey)
  end

end
```

to

```
describe 'is_tall?' do

  it "should return true for a tall user" do
    expect(tall_user_string.is_tall?).to be_truthy
  end

  it "should return false for a short user" do
    expect(user_string.is_tall?).to be_falsey
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a small typo, you need to close parentheses earlier:

```
describe 'is_tall?' do
  it "should return true for a tall user" do
    expect(tall_user_string.is_tall?).to be_truthy
  end

  it "should return false for a short user" do
    expect(user_string.is_tall?).to be_falsey
  end
end
```

And if you like William Shakespeare you can also write it like this:

```
describe 'is_tall?' do
  it "should return true for a tall user" do
    expect(tall_user_string.is_tall?).to be
  end

  it "should return false for a short user" do
    expect(user_string.is_tall?).not_to be
  end
end
```

Comment: oh I looove Shakespeare. Thanks!!